# How to iterate over enumerated Check List (check boxes) using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

How to iterate over enumerated Check List (check boxes) using JQuery?

Hello there, I have the following check list (containing two check boxes which have two different e-mail addresses in them):

```
<div id="emailCheckListId" class="checkList">
 <ul id="emailCheckListId_ul">
    <li>
        <label for="mycomponent.emailCheckList_0" class="checkListLabel">
            <input type="checkbox"  
                   value="johndoe1@example.com" 
                   id="mycomponent.emailCheckList_0" 
                   name="mycomponent.emailCheckList"/>
                   johndoe1@example.com
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="mycomponent.emailCheckList_1" class="checkListLabel">
            <input type="checkbox"  
                   value="johndoe2@example.com" 
                   id="mycomponent.emailCheckList_1" 
                   name="mycomponent.emailCheckList"/> 
                   johndoe2@example.com
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Am able to use a JavaScript event listener to populate / remove from a text field, every time a user clicks on an individual check box using this:

```
// Event listener which picks individual contacts
// and populates input field.
$('#emailCheckListId_ul input:checkbox').change(function() {
     // Declare array
     var emails = [];

     // Iterate through each array and put email addresses into array
     $('#emailCheckListId_ul input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
         emails.push($(this).val());
     });

     // Assign variable as To: text field by obtaining element's id.
     var textField = document.getElementById("mycomponent.textfield");

     // Add / Remove array from text field
     textField.value = emails;
 });
```

However, I now have an enumerated check list...  Just need to append / concatenate the index number (which I stored in an hidden field and can always obtain the
correct one), but can't seem to see how to pass in the second iterator's `input:checkbox:checked`.

Here's the HTML source of the checked list:

```
 <div id="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList" 
      class="checkList" 
      onclick="selectIndividualRecipients()">
      <ul id="mycomponentcomment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_ul">
          <li>
            <label for="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_0" 
                 class="checkListLabel">
               <input type="checkbox"  
                      value="johndoe1@example.com" 
                      id="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_0" 
                      name="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList"/>
                      johndoe1@example.com
            </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_1" 
               class="checkListLabel">
               <input type="checkbox"  
                      value="johndoe2@example.com" 
                      id="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_1" 
                      name="mycomponent.comment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList"/> 
                      johndoe2@example.com
        </label>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Uses an event listener which picks individual contacts
// and populates input field.
function selectIndividualRecipients() {

    var checkListPrefix = 'mycomponent.comment';    
    var index = document.getElementById("commentHiddenField").value;
    var checkListPostfix = '.replyToRecipientsCheckList_ul';
    var event =  checkListPrefix + index + checkListPostfix;
    
    $(event).change(function() {

         // Declare array
         var emails = [];

         // Iterate through each array and put email addresses into array
    
         // THIS DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING:
         var test = '#' + event.attr('id') + 'input:check:checked';
         $(test).each(function() {
         alert('inside iterator');
         alert('this.val: ' + $(this).val());
         emails.push($(this).val());
         alert('emails = ' + emails);
    });

    // Assign variable to Reply To: text field by obtaining element's id.
    var textField = document.getElementById(indexedReplyTextField);

    // Add / Remove array from text field
    textField.value = emails;
}
```

The browser says that (`$test).each()` throws an exception which is not caught and this is not allowed...

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Probably won't solve the problem, but I think you need to close the `each(function{` after the line `alert('emails = ' + emails);`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your var test declaration as follows?

```
var test = '#' + event.attr('id') + ' input:checkbox:checked';
```

Notice the space before input and checkbox instead of check.

Comment: I think I did try that... Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an easier method:

```
$('div.checkList').delegate('input', 'change', function() {
   textField.value = $('div.checkList ul li input:checked').map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
   }).get().join('; ');
});
```

Comment: thanks rkw, but I need it to iterate over mycomponentcomment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_ul instead of emailCheckListId. The first HTML and JavaScript was for a non-enumerated ul list. This situation is an enumerated ul list which is mycomponentcomment0.replyToRecipientsCheckList_ul. I need access to its line items.